# undefined is not an object _react.PropTypes.array

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-snap-carousel

I am using React Native (Expo CLI). Since i reinstalled npm i have this error when i try to run `npm start` I found some similar erros related to `react-native-snap-carousel` (i am using it).

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react.PropTypes.array')    
at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error   
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:95:4 in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:141:19 in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules\@react-native\polyfills\error-guard.js:49:36 in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
at node_modules\metro-runtime\src\polyfills\require.js:203:6 in guardedLoadModule
at http://192.168.1.6:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:202384:3 in global code
```

So, inside it's main file is imported `{PropTypes} from "react";` and changed to `import PropTypes from "prop-types";` (previously installed). Also changed `propTypes.items: PopTypes.array.isRequired` to `propTypes.items:PropTypes.array`, same to `slideStyle` (because I started getting new errors related to `items` and `slideStyle` are required) but now i am receiving new errors like this[image: new errors].
All errors are related to `react-native-snap-carousel`

Here is my package.json [image: package.json]

Here is how i use `react-native-snap-carousel`

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
} from "react-native";
import { getBannersApi } from "../../Api/HomeBanner";
import Carousel, { Pagination } from "react-native-snap-carousel";
import { size } from "lodash";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";

import { SERVER_RESOURCERS } from "../../Utils/Constans";

const width = Dimensions.get("window").width;
const height = 160;

export default function Banner() {
  const [banners, setBanners] = useState(null);
  const [banneActive, setBanneActive] = useState(0);
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const response = await getBannersApi();
      setBanners(response.data);
    })();
  }, []);

  const goToProduct = (id) => {
    navigation.push("product", { idProduct: id });
  };

  if (!banners) return null;

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPress={() => goToProduct(item.attributes.product.data.id)}
      >
        <Image
          style={styles.carousel}
          source={{
            uri: `${SERVER_RESOURCERS}${item.attributes.banner.data[0].attributes.formats.small.url}`,
          }}
        />
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Carousel
        layout="default"
        data={banners}
        sliderWidth={width}
        itemWidth={width}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        loop={true}
        onSnapToItem={(i) => setBanneActive(i)}
        autoplay={true}
        autoplayInterval={5000}
        autoplayDelay={2000}
      />
      <Pagination
        dotsLength={size(banners)}
        activeDotIndex={banneActive}
        inactiveDotOpacity={0.6}
        inactiveDotScale={0.6}
        containerStyle={styles.dotsContainer}
        dotStyle={styles.dot}
        dotColor={styles.dot.backgroundColor}
        inactiveDotColor={styles.dot.backgroundColor}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed `react-native-snap-carousel` is not supported anymore so I migrated to `react-native-reanimated-carousel`